# Problems with Dateish strings

Tags: date, mixins, raku

This code (for checking the changed timestamp of the current directory):

```
my $date = ".".IO.changed.DateTime.yyyy-mm-dd but Dateish; 
say $date;
```

yields the error:

```
«Ambiguous call to 'gist(Str+{Dateish}: )'; these signatures all match:␤:  (Str:D: *%_)␤:(Dateish:D:   │ avalenn
                 | *%_)␤  in block <unit> at <tmp> line 1␤␤»
```

Without the [`Dateish` mix in](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Dateish), the string is simply `2018-05-12`. Using any other kind of `Dateish` function, like `.week-year` also yields a different error:

```
«Str+{Dateish}␤Invocant of method 'Bridge' must be an object instance of type 'Int', not a type      │ a3r0
                 | object of type 'Int'.  Did you forget a '.new'?␤  in block <unit> at <tmp> line 1␤␤»
```

Does it simply mean that you can't mix in a string with Dateish? I've done something similar with hours without a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question, we should look at that role:

```
my role Dateish {
    has Int $.year;
    has Int $.month;     # should be int
    has Int $.day;       # should be int
    has Int $.daycount;
    has     &.formatter;

    ...
    multi method Str(Dateish:D:) {
        &!formatter ?? &!formatter(self) !! self!formatter
    }
    multi method gist(Dateish:D:) { self.Str }
    ...
}
```

So, role `Dateish` has several attributes, and the methods use those attributes to calculate their return values.

When you do `$some-string but Dateish`, you are not doing anything to initialize the attributes, and thus method calls that use them (potentially indirectly) fail in interesting ways.

How do you get a `Dateish` object from a `DateTime` then? Well, `DateTime` is one, already, or you can coerce to `Date` if that is what you want:

```
my $date = ".".IO.changed.DateTime.Date; say $date
```

You might also try to instantiate a `Dateish` by supplying all attributes, but I don't see any advantage over just using `Date` as intended.

Comment: Is there a way to mix-in an object instead of a type initializing it? Not in this case, since it seems that Dateish can't be initialized, only cloned... Besides, somehow I thought that mixing in a class performed some kind of initialization. What's the use case for this kind of mixins then?